# Trainable parameters explode in CNN , how to control them and yet get desired accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, cnn

I am building a CNN mode using CSV of size (79999, 11)
Here is my model below. When I do a model summary it gives me close to two billion trainable parameters , which my laptop or even AWS Ec2 is not able to handle. What am I doing wrong ? New to ML pls help. I want trainable parameters to be something, which my 4 core 12 GB i5 can handle. Right now my Kernel just hangs.
Thanks --
Code :

```
seed=42;tf.reset_default_graph(); tf.set_random_seed(seed); np.random.seed(seed)

model = Sequential()
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')  # th = (channels, rows, cols) ; tf = (rows, cols, channels)
#model.add(Convolution2D(30, 5, 5, border_mode= 'valid' ,input_shape = (1, 14, 5), activation= 'relu' ))
#model.add(Convolution2D(30, 5, 5, border_mode= 'valid' ,input_shape = image_shape, activation= 'relu' ))
#model.add(Conv2D(30, (5, 5), border_mode= 'valid' ,input_shape = image_shape, activation= 'relu', padding="valid" ))
#xxmodel.add(Conv2D(30, (5, 5), input_shape = (num_of_images, num_colors_per_pixel, rows_per_image, cols_per_image), activation= 'relu', padding="valid" ))
model.add(Conv2D(15, (5, 5), input_shape = image_shape, activation= 'relu', padding="valid" ))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 1)))
#model.add(Convolution2D(20, 3, 3, activation= 'relu' ))
model.add(Conv2D(10, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(8, activation= 'relu' ))
#model.add(Dense(25, activation= 'relu' ))
model.add(Dense(1, activation= 'softmax' ))

model.compile(loss= 'binary_crossentropy' , optimizer= 'adam' ,
              metrics=[ 'accuracy' ])
print ('model.input_shape  ', model.input_shape)
model.summary()
Result :
model.input_shape   (None, 1, 500, 559932)
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 15, 496, 559928)   390       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 15, 496, 559928)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 10, 494, 559926)   1360      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 10, 494, 559926)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 10, 494, 559926)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 2766034440)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 8)                 2212827552
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 9         
=================================================================
Total params: 22,128,277,287
Trainable params: 22,128,277,287
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: The problem is that you've attempt to use a wrong input for you cnn. Your input signal I guess is (1, 11). You've employed 2d cnn.